# Как анимировать view за пределы своего контейнера?

Tags: android, android-animation

Использую translate анимацию. Вьюхи перемещаются только в пределах своих контейнеров. Как заставить их летать по всему экрану?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

у ViewGroup есть несколько параметров, которые могут вам помочь

**clipChildren**

```
android:clipChildren="false"
...
viewGroup.setClipChildren(false);
```

Определяет - есть ли ограничения рисования для childView внутри его границ или нет.

**clipToPadding**

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
...
viewGroup.setClipToPadding(false);
```

Определяет - будет ли ViewGroup обрезать его дочерние элементы